# Search strings in (.gz) zipped folder with files in it

Tags: grep

Need to search strings in (.gz) zipped folder with files in it.

Sample Folder -

```
PROD_009_010919_0110.tar.gz
```

Files inside - `PROD_009_010919.log01, PROD_009_010919.log02, PROD_009_010919.log03`.......etc

Command - `zgrep -ia *123456* PROD_*` 
is not fetching the expected results.

the expected output - i should search the string '123456' in all the files in the zipped folders and display the string containing files.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to extract a piece of text from one of the files in the archive, or do you want to test whether a particular file is part of the archive?  In short, what is the expected result?

Comment: gzip does not zip folders, only files so I suppose that you are using another zipper apart from gz right? Have you checked with gzip -l the content of of your gz?

Comment: @Dasel, based on the filename it seems to be `tar`-ed before `gzip`-ed

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov; I did not saw the name; in that case we need first to know which is expected, as otherwise is difficult to debug. Anyway it would be much easier to do tar -ztvf PROD_009_010919_0110.tar.gz and after that use a normal grep to search the wanted result, but of course the ideal would be to have a sample of the expected output.

Comment: the expected result need to be - i should get the string 1234536 containing list of files. 

zgrep -ia *1234536* PROD_*

Comment: @Dasel - i would do the tar before if it is one or two files, but i have some hundreds of zipped files where i need to search the string and extract the result.

Comment: @PraveenKP Could you please [edit] your question and mention what it is that you expect as output? I see your comment saying "i should get the string 1234536 containing list of files", but I don't understand what you mean by it.

Comment: Kusal, edited the question - to be more specific, i ll state in simpler words here - i need to search some content/string in the zipped folder (.tar.gz) where this zipped folder inturn have the (*.log01, *log02, etc) files inside it. so in actual, i need to search a string/content int he zipped folder log files and should display the file names in which the string exists.


hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

This prints out the list of files inside the tarball matching the given pattern:

```
tar --ignore-command-error -xvf PROD_009_010919_0110.tar.gz --to-command="grep -FH 1234536 -" | grep -B1 --no-group-separator '(standard input)' | grep -v '(standard input)'
```

The `--to-command` option extracts each file and sends to the standard input of the `grep` command. The `-v` option lists each file as they're processed.

The `--ignore-command-error` is used to ignore the exit status when `grep` cannot find a match. Because of the `-H` option (print filename) used with the `grep` command, each matching line is prefixed with a '(standard input)' string.

This results in output of the following kind from the `tar` command:

```
file1
file2
(standard input): <matched lines from file2>
file3
(standard input): <matched lines from file3>
```

Piping this output allows the two `grep` commands to extract only the file names which are immediately followed by the '(standard input)' string on the next line. This processing could probably be improved using a regex to match the pattern instead of the two sequential `grep` commands I have used here.

The resulting output in this case will be:

```
file2
file3
```

Comment: We still don't actually know whether the user wants to grep filenames or file contents.

Comment: File content Kusal.

Comment: @Kusalananda I was going by the OP's earlier comment that stated '_i should get the string 1234536 containing list of files_'. In any case, the OP has just clarified with another comment that they want to grep through the contents and then list the files containing matches.

Comment: @PraveenKP To reply to a specific user, you should use the '@username' notation so that they get a notification for your comment. In any case, I believe my answer should work as per your requirements. Let me know if you see any problems.